# Symfony: Set cells background color using liuggio/ExcelBundle

Tags: php, excel, symfony

I want to set cells background color in excel using liuggio/ExcelBundle
I try this code:

```
$phpExcelObject->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getStyle('A1')->applyFromArray(
    array(
        'fill' => array(
            'color' => array('rgb'=>'FF0000'),
         )
    )
);`
```

but it doesn't work

This question is Corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change to this:

```
$phpExcelObject->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getStyle('A1')->applyFromArray(
    array(
        'fill' => array(
            'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
            'color' => array('rgb'=>'FF0000'),
         )
    )
);`
```

You need to specify fill type